# Action payload is undefined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, react-redux

This is the error that I am receiving **Cannot read property 'data' of undefined**

```
switch (action.type){
case REGISTER_USER:
        console.log("Action ", action);// This prints {type: "REGISTER_USER", payload: undefined}
     return [action.payload.data, ...state];
    }
return state;
```

I think this is happening because `Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}`
is the current state of the promise. 
Here is my action

```
function registerUser(details, callback) {
console.log(details);
const request = axios.post(URL, {
    "email": details['email'],
    "name": details['username'],
    "password": details['password']
}).then(() =>callback());
console.log(request);
return{
    type: REGISTER_USER,
    payload: request
   };
}
```

The callback that am passing is shown below

```
onFormSubmit(values){
    this.props.registerUser(values
        ,() =>{
        this.props.history.push("/login");
        }
    );
}
```

My question is how can I return the action only when the Promise is resolved? I am a beginer in react correct me where necessary.

Comment: I'd recommend starting with the the [Asynchronous Actions](https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) section of the docs, along with the ['real world' example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your action  is not valid .

while your  action  contains async process  you have to follow this logic

```
function asyncStart(){
   return { type:'ASYNC_REQUEST' };
}
function asyncError(e){
 return {type:'ASYNC_ERROR', payload:{error:e}};
}
function asyncSuccess(res){
  return {type:'ASYNC_SUCCESS',payload:{result:res}};
}
function asyncMethod(){      
 return (dispatch, getState)=>{ 
     let state  = getState(); /// if you require state 
     dispatch(asyncStart());// or use  {type:'Something',payload:....};
      anAsyncSomething.then((val)=>{
          dispatch(asyncSuccess(val));  
       })
      .catch((e)=>{
          dispatch(asyncError(e));
     });
  }
```

}

i hope this will help to understand how redux handles async operations .